# Trying to make modal data dynamic with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I am working on quickview for an e-commerce project. I have done the following so far:

```
function quickView(){
    $('.btn-quick-view').on('click', function(){
    let id = $(this).attr('value');
    let url = '{{ route("quick", ":data") }}';
    url = url.replace(":data", id);
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success(response){
            let html = "<div class='modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered' role='document'><div class='modal-content'><span class='modal-close' data-dismiss='modal'><i class='icon-cross2'></i></span><article class='ps-product--detail ps-product--fullwidth ps-product--quickview'><div class='ps-product__header'><div class='ps-product__thumbnail' data-vertical='false'><div class='ps-product__images' data-arrow='true'>";
            $.each(response.images, function(key, value){
            html += "<div class='item'><img src='"+value.image+"'></div>";
            });
            html += "</div></div><div class='ps-product__info'><h1>"+response.name+"</h1><div class='ps-product__meta'><p>Brand:<a href='shop-default.html'>Sony</a></p><div class='ps-product__rating'><select class='ps-rating' data-read-only='true'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='1'>2</option><option value='1'>3</option><option value='1'>4</option><option value='2'>5</option></select><span>(1 review)</span></div></div><h4 class='ps-product__price'>$36.78 – $56.99</h4><div class='ps-product__desc'><p>Sold By:<a href='shop-default.html'><strong> Go Pro</strong></a></p>description</div><div class='ps-product__shopping'><a class='ps-btn ps-btn--black' href='#'>Add to cart</a><a class='ps-btn' href='#'>Buy Now</a><div class='ps-product__actions'><a href='#'><i class='icon-heart'></i></a><a href='#'><i class='icon-chart-bars'></i></a></div></div></div></div></article></div></div>";
            $('#product-quickview').html(html);
            $.getScript('/frontend/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js');
        },
        error: function(response){
            toastr.error('Something went wrong!');
        }
    });
    })
}
quickView();
```

Since this model uses slick for showing product images, I want the jquery to work. I tried to load jquery  with `$.getScript('/frontend/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js');` but it did not work. What can I do for this model to work dynamically?

Comment: You mean you cannot add/include jquery in your template file? Also you can try cdn link.

Comment: @PharsaThapa The jquery gets included normally but here I want to reload jquery after my ajax call.

Comment: But  you are working on jQuery codes even before calling ajax. i didn't understand, what is the purpose of loading the same lib, which is already loaded.

Comment: @PharsaThapa My jquery works but since I am placing div through ajax I want the plugin like slick to work on the div place through ajax.

Comment: Did you try with cdn path instead of your local file?

Comment: @PharsaThapa Yes I did.

Comment: i haven't done any quickview or slick so far. But i know much about ajax and modal dialogs. If you can share what you actually wanted to do, i may help you out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218567/discussion-between-pharsa-thapa-and-alisha-lamichhane).

Comment: why you need to use jquery again?? just call the slick function after ajax success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function quickView(){
$('.btn-quick-view').on('click', function(){
let id = $(this).attr('value');
let url = '{{ route("quick", ":data") }}';
url = url.replace(":data", id);
$.ajax({
method: "GET",
url: url,
dataType: 'json',
success(response){
let html = "<div class='modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered' role='document'>
  <div class='modal-content'><span class='modal-close' data-dismiss='modal'><i class='icon-cross2'></i></span>
    <article class='ps-product--detail ps-product--fullwidth ps-product--quickview'>
      <div class='ps-product__header'>
        <div class='ps-product__thumbnail' data-vertical='false'>
          <div class='ps-product__images' data-arrow='true'>";
            $.each(response.images, function(key, value){
            html += "<div class='item'><img src='"+value.image+"'></div>";
            });
            html += "</div>
        </div>
        <div class='ps-product__info'>
          <h1>"+response.name+"</h1>
          <div class='ps-product__meta'>
            <p>Brand:<a href='shop-default.html'>Sony</a></p>
            <div class='ps-product__rating'><select class='ps-rating' data-read-only='true'>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='1'>2</option>
                <option value='1'>3</option>
                <option value='1'>4</option>
                <option value='2'>5</option>
              </select><span>(1 review)</span></div>
          </div>
          <h4 class='ps-product__price'>$36.78 – $56.99</h4>
          <div class='ps-product__desc'>
            <p>Sold By:<a href='shop-default.html'><strong> Go Pro</strong></a></p>description
          </div>
          <div class='ps-product__shopping'><a class='ps-btn ps-btn--black' href='#'>Add to cart</a><a class='ps-btn' href='#'>Buy Now</a>
            <div class='ps-product__actions'><a href='#'><i class='icon-heart'></i></a><a href='#'><i class='icon-chart-bars'></i></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>";
$('#product-quickview').html(html);
//initialize your slick lib
$('.product-images').slick();
$.getScript('/frontend/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js');
},
error: function(response){
toastr.error('Something went wrong!');
}
});
})
}
quickView();
```